# Apache2 Ubuntu: Virtualhost redirects to localhost

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I wanted to set up a virtualhost for my apache2 running on my computer. So when I browse to: "invision.jan.pcsg" I get the page contents/folder structure from "/var/www/html/invision"

This is the virtualhost file "invision.jan.pcsg.conf" I created:

```
<VirtualHost invision.jan.pcsg:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/invision
    ServerName invision.jan.pcsg 
    ServerAlias hkl.mor.pcsg hkl_at.mor.pcsg


    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride FileInfo
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/invision/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

When I browse to "invision.jan.pcsg" now, I get redirected to localhost and the "php is working"-page is displayed.

When browsing to "jan.pcsg" the folder contents of "/var/www" is displayed.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: This question fits better on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but in my case I realized I had forgotten to enable the host .conf file.

```
sudo a2ensite myvhost.conf
```

Then I just reloaded apache and everything worked out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DocumentRoot to directory where your web application ('view' if its MVC) is located.
Usually its : DocumentRoot /home/www-data/ /